# Changing AJAX Chat style sheet

Tags: css, ajax, chat

I am looking at loggedIn.html for my Ajax chat and would like to be able to change the css style sheet on the fly. To begin with I made a copy of the Uranium.css stylesheet (which is the only one I am supporting in my chat) which I will be modifying, and I will have a way to switch between the two. However, the switching is not my problem -- I know how to do that already. I am trying to figure out how to apply the new CSS file to the chat. It appears the following line in the `<head></head>` tags is determining the styles:

```
[DRUPAL_AJAX_STYLE_SHEETS/]
```

I would like to point it specifically to my own stylesheet (for now, let's call it "myStyles.css"). I commented out the above line and put the following line below it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyles.css" />
```

However, when I apply this change the chat loses all of its formatting. I am not exactly sure what `[DRUPAL_AJAX_STYLE_SHEETS/]` is doing, but it's clearly doing more than just setting the style.

How can I tell the chat to use my own stylesheet?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MrLister, I intended to specify the "head" tags but I must have gotten distracted =P

Comment: You did actually specify them, but they ended up invisible, because SO didn't know what to do with them.

Comment: Ahh, because I forgot the "accent" marks. I would never have caught that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found the answer, and it was a fairly stupid mistake. It turns out I wasn't using the correct portion of the chat path to point it to the stylesheet. I was trying:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyles.css" />
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="var/www/html/sites/all/modules/ajaxchat/chat/css/myStyles.css" />
```

but it turns out I need to start the path at "sites" instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/all/modules/ajaxchat/chat/css/myStyles.css" />
```

Once I did that I was able to comment out `[DRUPAL_AJAX_STYLE_SHEETS/]` and the page used my own formatting.